# Keep shaving stubble from getting into my eyes

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, shaving

My name is Tony and I have a significant problem.

**Each time I shave**, no matter what precautions I am taking, such as wearing goggles to shield my eyes, I get cut facial hair not fall to the floor but **get some attracted into my eyes** causing serious discomfort and pain to subsequently extract it.

This has been an issue for a year or two. I have tried to investigate this thoroughly in terms of **my body being charged with static electricity**.

I can even say that **if I am holding my electric razor, the cut hairs from it will literally rise into my eyes**.

> **Things that maybe an issue:**
>
> - I do have carpeting in a single room I use extensively which although I keep clean, dispenses a fair amount of dust in the immediate rooms.
> - The situation is worse in the winter months with dry air from the heaters and I have recently bought a humidifier to add moisture to the air.
> - I use an electric shaver

**Question**
What is the best way to keep facial hair from getting into my eyes?

Comment: Use a normal razor? and use shaving cream? Use something that isnt powered by electricity?

Comment: That's also my question. When you use shaving cream + normal razor it happens?

Comment: Also I have never heard of wearing goggles while shaving...

Answer (score 4):

**Shave wet.**

If you aren't willing to switch to a bladed razor (which would use shaving cream), you can switch to a wet/dry electric razor.

**Product Search: [Wet/Dry Electric Razor](https://www.google.com/search?q=wet+dry+electric+razor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=wet+dry+electric+razor&tbm=shop)**

You don't need to use shaving cream with these either. If you just wet your face with water or any lotion before shaving, it will cut down the flyaway stubble to practically zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **swimming goggles**?

To get rid of electric charge you could try to touch your radiator or anything that is electrically conductive and somewhat connected to ground.